# New experiments involving Ramanujan primes: Benford's law

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, st.statistics, integer-sequences, experimental-mathematics

I know that in the literature there are interesting articles involving the sequence of Ramanujan primes, I refer the [*Ramanujan Prime*](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RamanujanPrime.html) from the online encyclopedia Wolfram MathWorld. This week I wondered what about experimental mathematics concerning this sequence of prime numbers (in the past I've known for example the article  $1/f$ *noise in the distribution of prime numbers* by Marek Wolf, Physica A: Statistical Mechanics and its Applications Vol. **241**, Issue 3–4, (1997), pp. 493-499). I have thought the following question inspired by the article *Un nuevo patrón en los números primos* that the author Bartolo Luque refers in his column *Juegos matemáticos* of a scientific journal, the Spanish edition of Scientific American, that is the journal Investigación y Ciencia, pages 91-93 (Julio 2019). He is author of [1].

> **Question.** Do the first-digit frecencies of Ramanujan primes satisfy a Benford's law? **Many thanks.**

Thus I'm asking if you know how to deduce, or to disprove it, (showing your computational evidence or reasonings) if first-digit frecuencies of Ramanujan primes obey some Benford's law. I add that Wikipedia has an article dedicated to [*Benford's law.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law)

I hope that my question is interesting, feel free to add comments about it. Also if my question is in the literature answer it as a reference request.

### References:

[1] Bartolo Luque and Lucas Lacasa, *The First-Digit Frequencies of Prime Numbers and Riemann Zeta Zeros*, Proceedings: Mathematical, Physical and Engineering Sciences Vol. 465, No. 2107 (Jul. 8, 2009), pp. 2197-2216 (Royal Society).

Comment: I've added the tag (st.statistics) instead of other tags as (analytic-number-theory), feel free to edit the tags as you consider, or improving the grammar of the body.

Comment: I think the answer depends on what distribution over Ramanujan primes you choose.

Comment: Good afternoon @WillSawin , and many thanks for your comment, I ask if it **does make sense a Benford's law for the sequence of first digit of Ramanujan primes**. (On the other hand and unrelated to our concern, as you see in my introductory paragraph I evoke a different experiment, I didn't it, thus if you want to study the Fourier transform of such sequence as did Marek Wolf and is explained in the book of Crandall and Pomerance, feel free to study if in the sequence of Ramanujan primes there is noise)

Comment: Well, here is a question for you: Is there a Benford's law for the first digits of natural numbers? Can you state it? How would you test it empirically?

Comment: @Will, I don't see the problem here. You look at the first $n$ terms of a sequence; you count how many begin with the digit one (say); you divide that by $n$; you see whether the quotient has a limit as $n\to\infty$. If it does, and if that limit is $\log2$, then the sequence satisfies Benford (for the digit "one"). For the sequence of natural numbers, the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: It wouldn't be too hard for OP to include the definitions of "Ramanujan prime" and "Benford's Law" instead of making others users chase them offsite, would it?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sure, but I find "No, this sequence doesn't satisfy Benford's law, because it has polynomial growth and no sequence with polynomial growth satisfies Benford's law" unsatisfying, as it's telling you much more about how you've chosen to define Benford's law than about your sequence.

Comment: Benford's law is essentially nothing but an expression for the invariant (Haar) measure on the multiplicative group of positive reals. Therefore, asking whether a certain distribution satisfies Benford's law is the same as asking whether this distribution is asymptotically invariant in the multiplicative scale.

Comment: @Will, are there inequivalent ways to define Benford's Law?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sure, we could consider a probability distribution where each $n$ is weighted by $n^{-s}$ (times a constant multiple to make the total probability $1$), look at the frequency of each starting digit, and then take the limit of that frequency as $s \to 1$.

Comment: @Will, I've never seen Benford defined with any weights on the terms other than weight $1/n$ for each. People write that, say, the Fibonacci sequence follows Benford's Law; they don't feel obliged to add such a disclaimer as "if you weight each $n$ by $1$."

Comment: @GerryMyerson This is probably my fault for only being familiar with Benford's law in the context of real life phenomena (say, those approximately described by a power law), not the mathematical version for sequences like Fibonacci. I thought the $n^{-s}$ version was a natural abstraction of the real-life version to mathematical sequences of polynomial growth, say.

Comment: Many thanks to you @WillSawin and for the other professors in comments.  I need some days to read and understand the comment thread of this post. Any case I refer that I've read/my motivation was the article by Bartolo Luque from the journal Investigación y Ciencia **514** (Julio 2019). About the variation of Wolf's experiment I add the reference if some user or you are interested in it, that is the mentioned article or pages 429-430 and exercise 8.33 from Crandrall and Pomerance *Prime Numbers*, Springer (2005) for an arithmetic function counting the number of Ramanujan primes over intervals

Comment: I add a comment to emhasize that I've read previous interesting comments, also the comment about Haar measure (my knowledges about this subject it are poor, but I thanks such good comments)

Comment: Many thanks @MichaelHardy for your edit.

Comment: The following recent preprint ("Dirichlet, Sierpinski, Benford") by Pollack and Singha Roy may be of interest: http://pollack.uga.edu/DSB.pdf

It does not discuss Ramanujan primes but does discuss one sense (pointed out by Bombieri) in which primes obey Benford's law.

Comment: Many thanks @so-calledfriendDon , it seems that isn't at my (research) level, but sure that I understand some extracts of the article, and your reference will be very interesting for the professor here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am following what is being asked, the answer is no.

Set $R$ to be the set of Ramanujan primes. Let $R_d$ be the set of Ramanujan primes with lead digit $d$. For a set of positive integers integers $S$, we'll write $S(x)$ to be the number of elements in S which are at most $x$.  Then you are asking whether for any $d=1,2, \cdots 9$ we have
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{R_d(x)}{R(x)} =\log_{10} \left(\frac{d+1}{d}\right)$$

This statement is  false. Let $Ram_n$ be the $n$th Ramanujan prime. Then by [Sondow's theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.5232) $Ram_n$ is asymptotic to the $2n$th prime, which is asymptotic to $2n \log 2n \sim 2n \log n$  by the prime number theorem. So $$R(x) \sim \frac{x}{2\log x}.$$

Now, set $x=(10^t)$ Then we have (neglecting small error terms) $$R_9(x) \geq R(x)) - R(\frac{9}{10}x) = \frac{x}{2 \log x} -  \frac{\frac{9}{10}x}{2  \log x} = \frac{x}{10 (2)\log x} .$$

So for this set of value of $x$ we have $R_9(x)/R(x)$ is at least about $\frac{1}{10}$. But $\log_{10} \frac{10}{9}$ is much smaller, a little under $0.046.$

Note that this proof really doesn't use anything deep about the Ramanujan primes other than their asymptotic. In general, for any set of integers $S$ where $$S(x) \sim \frac{cx}{(\log x)^k}$$ for some positive constants $c$ and $k$, it will fail the base $10$ version of Benford's law. And this will apply to any other base $b>2$ by the same reasoning. Base $b$ will always have too many elements starting with $b-1$. (And of course in base $b=2$ Benford's law is trivial.) In order to have a Benford's law distribution one generally needs to be growing at least as slowly as $x^{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha <1$ or not have a good asymptotic at all. Edit: Actually see Will's comment below, one in fact needs a much stronger density requirement than this to have any hope of satisfying Benford's law.

Comment: I don't understand the last comment. Let $S$ be a set of integers and let $f(n)$ be the number of such integers less than $n$. Then if $S$ satisfies Benford's law, we have $f( (k+1) \cdot 10^n)= (1+o(1)) f( k \cdot 10^n)$ for any $1 \leq k \leq 9$, since otherwise the frequency of numbers with leading digit $k$ would be different at the two points. Combining this for $k$ from $1$ to $n$, we get $f( 10^{n+1}) = (1+o (1)) f(10^n)$, i.e. $f(n)$ grows slower than $n^{\alpha}$ for any $\alpha$. So $\alpha<1$ or the lack of a good asymptotic is not really enough.

Comment: @WillSawin You are absolutely correct. I convinced myself when I made that satisfying Benford's law implied that one was growing no more than $x^\alpha$  for any $\alpha$. I did not have a set in mind that satisfied it. You are correct to point out that the much stronger statement about what the set needs to satisfy is in fact true.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, and your attention and the attention of yours colleagues (professors) of this post and my recently deleted post about mathematicians (now I was disconnected). I need some days to read and understand  the comment thread of this post and your excellent answer.

Comment: The fraction $R_d(x)/R(x)$ should oscillate, with minima near $d10^t$ and maximal near $(d+1)10^t$. I suspect density might exist and satisfy Benford's law in logarithmic density sense.